# How does a level shifter based on a comparator work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator

What is the effect of grounding the power rails of an comparator?

(I mean grounding V+ and V-)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSeHsR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I understand this works like the clippers with diodes, but I haven't found a clear
explanation. Could someone explain it?

Comment: The comparator fails to work and any input you apply may destroy it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the common-mode range of the comparator includes ground, the output will be unpredictable in that case because the offset voltage of the comparator may be + or -. When both inputs are equal (0 in this case), the effective input voltage is the offset voltage.

If you simulate it, you may or may not get a result that is the same as a real circuit -- it depends on the accuracy of the model used in simulation. Note that the offset voltage is unpredictable (+ or -), and its statistics are not usually available in consumer-level simulations. Even if the simulator gives a high or low output, this doesn't reflect that in a batch of IC samples, some will give a high; some a low.

Comment: I think the OP said that he wants to tie the Vcc and Vss pins of the op amp to GND. not the input pins. But yes, the provided schematics is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

The effect of grounding V+ and V- is magic smoke. What are you trying to accomplish with this circuit?

I have that feeling that you meant 'grounding the inverting and non-inverting inputs'? In which case, you will get absolutely nothing.

If you mean, either grounding the inverting OR the non-inverting inputs, you will get a zero-crossing detector.

Please clarify your question

Comment: The concept is precisely the zero crossing detector.